# A single datepicker for multiple dash tables

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I would like to select dates in several tables, using dash_table . This works when using a different date picker for each table, but not when using a single date picker for all separate tables.

A simple reproducible example shows a single table, and data can be selected and displayed for different dates (here 1st, 2nd, or 3rd January).

*My question:* how to make three tables, – one for each country -, using a *single* date picker (not three). Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions!

**Modules**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, Event
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

**Fictive DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dd':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-03'], 'country':['Belgium', 'Belgium','France', 'France', 'Belgium', 'France', 'Belgium', 'Germany'], 'value':[10,20,30,10,15,25,5,70]})
```

**Script**

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True

currentday = 1
currentmonth = 1
currentyear = 2019

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H4('All countries'),
        dcc.DatePickerSingle(
            id='my-date-picker-single1',
            min_date_allowed=dt(2012, 1, 1),
            max_date_allowed=dt(2019, 2, 25),
            initial_visible_month=dt(currentyear, currentmonth, currentday),
            date=dt(currentyear, currentmonth, currentday),
            disabled=False
        ),

        dcc.Store(id="selected-rows1", storage_type="memory"),
        html.Div(id="tables-container1"),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id="table1",
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in ['dd', 'country', 'value'] ],

            style_cell_conditional=[
                {
                    'if':{'filter':'Country eq "France"'},
                    'backgroundColor':'rgb(150, 150, 150)'
                }


            ] + [
                {'if': {'column_id': c},
                 'textAlign': 'left'
                } for c in ['dd', 'country']
            ],

            sorting=True,
            sorting_type='multi',
            sorting_settings=[],
        )

    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("selected-rows1", "data"),
    [Input("my-date-picker-single1", "date")],
    [State("selected-rows1", "data")],
)

def display_output(value, storage):
    if value is not None:
        return {"selected_rows1": df[df["dd"].str.contains(value)].to_json()}

@app.callback(
    Output("table1", "data"),
    [Input("table1", "sorting_settings"), Input("selected-rows1", "data")],
)
def update_graph(sorting_settings, rows):
    _df = pd.read_json(rows["selected_rows1"])
    if sorting_settings is not None and len(sorting_settings):
        for setting in sorting_settings:
            _df.sort_values(
                by=setting["column_id"],
                ascending=(setting["direction"] == "asc"),
                inplace=True,
            )

        return _df.to_dict("rows")

    else:
        return _df.to_dict("rows")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Your advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [multiple callbacks](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2). Check section on "Multiple Outputs". Example:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("selected-rows1", "data"),
    [Input("my-date-picker-single1", "date")],
    [State("selected-rows1", "data")])
def display_output_1(value, storage):
    if value is not None:
        return {"selected_rows1": df[df["dd"].str.contains(value)].to_json()}

@app.callback(
    Output("selected-rows2", "data"),
    [Input("my-date-picker-single1", "date")],
    [State("selected-rows2", "data")])
def display_output_2(value, storage):
    if value is not None:
        return {"selected_rows2": df[df["dd"].str.contains(value)].to_json()}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This only displays the output from the first callback, not the second.

Comment: Both callbacks accept the same input and direct it to different outputs. I assume you want the same date for each table?

Comment: Absolutely. Same date, but each table represents a different country. In this case for ex. table1 is Belgium, table2 is France etc.

Comment: I am not then sure why it would not work, assuming `selected-rows1` is your `table1` id, `selected-rows2`  your `table2` id etc. Can you post full code?

Comment: Works now! It was an error in the table IDs. Thank you very much!